# How to print specific duplicate line based on fields number

Tags: awk, duplicates

I need to print out only one of various consecutive lines with same first field, and the one must be the one with "more fields in its last field". That means that last field is a set of words, and I need to print the line with more elements in its last field. In case of same number of max elements in last field, any of the max is ok.

Example input:

```
("aborrecimento",[Noun],[Masc],[Reg:Sing],[Bulk])
("aborrecimento",[Noun],[Masc],[Reg:Sing],[Device,Concrete,Count])
("aborrecimento",[Noun],[Masc],[Reg:Sing],[])
("adiamento",[Noun],[Masc],[Reg:Sing],[])
("adiamento",[Noun],[Masc],[Reg:Sing],[Count])
("adiamento",[Noun],[Masc],[Reg:Sing],[VerbNom])
```

Example output:

```
("aborrecimento",[Noun],[Masc],[Reg:Sing],[Device,Concrete,Count])
("adiamento",[Noun],[Masc],[Reg:Sing],[VerbNom])
```

solution with awk would be nice, but no need of one liner.

Comment: Tried to extract which line should I print, and later print the line itself, but couldn't guess how to obtain the line from various candidates.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### generate index file

```
$ cat input.txt |
sed 's/,\[/|[/g' | 
awk -F'|' '
{if(!gensub(/[[\])]/, "", "g", $NF))n=0;else n=split($NF, a, /,/); print NR,$1,n}
' | 
sort -k2,2 -k3,3nr | 
awk '$2!=x{x=$2;print $1}' >idx.txt
```

### content of index file

```
$ cat idx.txt
2
5
```

### select lines

```
$ awk 'NR==FNR{idx[$0]; next}; (FNR in idx)' idx.txt input.txt
("aborrecimento",[Noun],[Masc],[Reg:Sing],[Device,Concrete,Count])
("adiamento",[Noun],[Masc],[Reg:Sing],[Count])
```

---

**Note:** no space in `input.txt`

Comment: It works just perfect. I have blank spaces but can substitute them for underscores. You exactly matched my point, I was trying to generate that idx.txt aswell, but didn't know about gensub function, I need to study awk deeper!!
Thank you very much!

Answer (score 2):

Use <kbd>[</kbd> as the field delimiter, then split the last field on <kbd>,</kbd>:

```
awk -F '[[]' '
    {split($NF, f, /,/)}
    length(f) > max[$1] {line[$1] = $0; max[$1] = length(f)}
    END {for (l in line) print line[l]}
' filename
```

---

Since order is important, an update:

```
awk -F '[[]' '
    {split($NF, f, /,/)}
    length(f) > max[$1] {line[$1] = $0; max[$1] = length(f); nr[$1] = NR}
    END {for (l in line) printf("%d\t%s\n", nr[$1], line[l])}
' filename |
sort -n |
cut -f 2-
```

Comment: Very nice solution, but it doesn't respect order as I need (sorry I didn't specify so). Applying sort to the output doesn't work either, since input contains non-ascii chars ("ab, áb, bb," becomes "ab, bb, áb")

Answer (score 0):

Something like this might work:

```
awk 'BEGIN {FS="["} 
     Ff != gensub("^([^,]+).*","\\1","g",$0) { Ff = gensub("^([^,]+).*","\\1","g",$0) ; Lf = $NF ; if (length(Ml) > 0) { print Ml } }
     Ff == gensub("^([^,]+).*","\\1","g",$0) { if (length($NF) > length(Lf)) { Lf=$NF ; Ml=$0 } }    
     END {if (length(Ml) > 0) { print Ml } }' INPUTFILE
```

[See here in action](http://ideone.com/8XHff). *BUT* it's not the solution you want to use, as this is rather a hack. And it fails you if you meant that your last field is longer if it contains more `,` separated elements than the length of your last element. (E.g. the above script happily reports `[KABLAMMMMMMMMMMM!]` as longer than `[A,B,C]`.)

Comment: Yep, longest last field is which contains more separeated elements, not char length.

Answer (score 0):

This might work for you:

```
sort -r file | sort -t, -k1,1 -u
```